# How to connect multiple bearerbox in Vsmppbox?

Tags: smpp, kannel, opensmpp, opensmppbox

How to connect multiple bearerbox for load balancing in Vsmppbox , my configuration file is

```
group=vsmppbox
id=VSMPPBOX
log-file=/var/log/kannel/vsmppbox.log
log-level=0
smpp-port=4721
database-type=mysql
database-config=mysql
database-enable-queue=1
inbound-queue-threads=10
outbound-queue-threads=10
auth-method=1
database-user-table=smpp_users
database-store-table=smpp_store
database-log-table=smpp_log
database-pdu-table=smpp_queued_pdu
database-route-table=smpp_route
database-ndnc-table=smpp_ndnc
database-spam-table=smpp_spam
database-template-table=smpp_template
database-sender-table=smpp_sender
database-version-table=smpp_version

group=mysql-connection
id=mysql
host=localhost
username=root
password=
database=kannel_smpp
max-connections=50

group=bearerbox-connection
id=SMPPBOX-TEST
host=localhost
port=13002

group=http-server
port=14010
password=vsmppbox

group=smpp-routing
routing-method=1
```

How to configure multiple bearerbox for MT SMS with same smsc_id in bearerbox and using same sms_ids in routing table in vsmppbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiple bearerbox connection is possible, you can use this configuration repeating in your config file,

```
 group=bearerbox-connection
id=SMPPBOX-TEST
host=localhost
port=13002

group=bearerbox-connection
id=SMPPBOX-TEST1
host=localhost
port=13003

group=bearerbox-connection
id=SMPPBOX-TEST2
host=localhost
port=13004
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

multiple bearerbox connection is possible,

```
group=bearerbox-connection
id=SMPPBOX-TEST
host=localhost
port=13002

group=bearerbox-connection
id=SMPPBOX-TEST1
host=localhost
port=13003

group=bearerbox-connection
id=SMPPBOX-TEST2
host=localhost
port=13004
```

you can use this configuration repeating in your config file,
 the `id` and `port` change ,